# Between two dates spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to select records between two dates using spring data jpa.
If I am using `BETWEEN` and `<=` and `>=` it is not working.
If I am using two dates it is not giving me any records and using one date it is working perfectly.

In my project i have multiple table join. Here i am taking simple example.

```sql
SELECT emp FROM Employee emp WHERE emp.joiningDate between :startDate and :startDate2;
```

My repository method is:

```java
List<Employee> findEmps(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("startDate2") Date startDate2);
    
@Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "JOIN_DATE")
private Date joiningDate;
    
repo.findEmps(dateFormat.parse("2021-03-22"), dateFormat.parse("2021-03-26"));
```

But is is not giving me **0** records.

But If I am using:

```sql
SELECT emp FROM Employee emp WHERE emp.joiningDate >= :startDate;
```

My repo is:

```java
List<Employee> findEmps(@Param("startDate") Date startDate);
```

Then it is giving me records. I an not able to understand this behavior.

Anyone has idea about this, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What does your data look like? Any chance the "join" date is smaller than `2021-03-26 00:00`? (note that if no time is given, the start of the day is assumed).

Comment: Dates in DB is saved like '2101-MAR-26'

Comment: Are they actually dates then and not strings? Is the value `2101-xxx` correct, i.e. is the year 2101?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Data JPA you can use `findByStartDateBetween` take a look at the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)